# Grid (Moving average) how to set moving distance?

Tags: qgis

I'm using Grid (Moving average) to get mean values of Point attribute in a circle of 20 m radius.

What is determining the step distance / the output pixel size? I can't find it in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/gridaverage.html). I would like to set I manually to for example 10 m.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what is determining step distance if used in QGIS GUI but as commented it is possible to set it using the optional parameters -outsize, -txe and txy.

For example to get 10 m pixels I use command below in terminal:

```
gdal_grid -zfield datafield -a average:radius1=20:radius2=20:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -txe 626400 629800 -tye 6680000 6682000 -outsize 340 200 -ot Float32 -of GTiff D:/folder/someinputpointshapefile.shp D:/folder/OUTPUT.tif
```

(To calculate outsize:

```
(6682000-668000)/10=340
(629800-626400)/10=200
```

)